# Relationship between weighted $r^2$, and $r^2$ of transformed data

Tags: regression, data-transformation, r-squared, weighted-regression

When regressing heteroscedastic data, recommended practice is to either

1. transform the data to remove heteroscedasticity
2. weight the data to compensate

So let's say we have some data

$ y = x + \epsilon y $

We could either try to fit $log(y)$ against $log(x)$, or we could weight each data point with $1/y$.

As these are considered equivalent approaches, I would expect the goodness-of-fit from either to be the same.  That is to say, denoting $r^2$ as the function that calculates $r^2$:

$ unweighted\ r^2 (log\ y,log\ x) = r^2 (y,x)\ weighted\ by\ 1/y$

However, this relationship doesn't appear to hold, at least not in my code.  Why are these quantities not the same?  (Or is my code just wrong...)

Comment: Could you add some references for your claims?